# После авторизации появляется черный экран

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

Не знаю точно из за чего это все произошло. Может что то поставил левое. Может обновление вышло и я его поставил. Помогите разобраться.
Все грузится нормально, появляется окно в котором я должен ввести пароль пользователя чтобы ввойти в систему. Но как только я ввожу пароль и захожу. Экран сразу тухнет. Курсора нету. Просто выключеный экран. Если был бы включен, то не много бы светился. В консоль зайти могу, `Ctrl+Alt+F1`. Экран не много подсвечивается, и норм заходит, появляется консоль. При входу через учетку Гость - все нормально. Загружается Unity, все ок. Вот сейчас через Гостя сижу. Может кто-то знает что делать?

Comment: для начала попробуйте переименовать каталог `~/.config` — многие настройки пользователя хранятся в этом каталоге.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin когда удалил папке, то все норм загрузилось, только все было чисто, как после установки. начала добавлять старые папки в  `~/.config` по одной. черный экран появился после того как я добавил файл `monitors.xml` в `~/.config`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно удалить папку `~/.config`(при этом сделать ее копию, только под другим названием, например `~/.config1`) и все загрузится только без настроек. И чтобы узнать из-за чего все было, нужно по порядку добавлять папки и файлы из `~/.config1` (который был заранее скопирован) в новый `~/.config`. И заметить после какого файла или папки появится черный экран. Когда узнали из-за чего все было, удалите этот файл или папку, а все остальное что осталось добавьте в новый `~/.config`.